# Should I deny unused request methods?

Tags: http, zend-framework, http-headers

In my Zend Framework MVC application I am using only two request methods: GET and POST.  I am wondering whether I should put a check in my base controller to throw an exception if the other request types are received (e.g. PUT or DELETE).

As far as I can see there are two areas for consideration:

1. Would it improve security at all?  Am I giving potential hackers a head start if I allow the framework to respond to PUT, DELETE, et al?
2. Would it interfere with correct operation of the site?  For example, do search engine bots rely on requests other than GET and POST?

Your ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: I would refuse any unrecognized methods. Otherwise you can't add support for them later. Bots will only search read-only methods such as GET.

Comment: I doubt this does anything security-wise. Potential hackers are already calling your code and you have to respond to *some* request which they can try to malform. (That is, unless the framework does some magic for POST request like automatically parse it and save data to the database, but that sounds pretty unlikely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People violate the api of your app/framework/site etc either due to errors or on purpose, to probe your site for weaknesses. (Only matters in frequency if your site is internal only or on the public net.)

If your site supports developers, then that'd be a possible reason to reply with a 405 code of method not allowed. Perhaps only if the session (assuming sessions) is marked as being in developer mode.

If you don't expect valid developers, then I recommend silently swallowing any bad input to make it harder for the bad guys.

Another reason not to give error messages in the normal case: the lack of an error message in a particular case can then be interpreted that the bad data made it further into your stack than other data--outlining a possible attack route.

And finally, error returns (type, delay before responding, and more) can be used to characterize a particular version of an app/framework etc. This can then be used to quickly locate other vulnerable installations once an attack vector is found.

Yes, the above is pessimistic, and I fondly remember the 80's when everybody responded to ping, echo and other diagnostic requests. But the bad guys are here and it is our responsibility to harden our systems. See this [TED video](http://www.ted.com/talks/danny_hillis_the_internet_could_crash_we_need_a_plan_b.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

The correct response code would be `405 Method Not Allowed`, including an `Allow: GET, POST`  header.

> 10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html